# My Frontend wont connect to my node.js websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

My Frontend wont connnect to my node.js websocket server, when i want to run it on another port than port 80. I cant run it on port 80 because my apache is already on port 80. Im currently trying it on port 39100 it shouldnt be a problem with the firewall.

My node.js websocket file runs on port 39100:
[it runs on port 39100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJPyG.png)

In my node.js websocket server:

```
    const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 39100})
```

My Frontend file which trys to connect to this port

In my Frontend File:

```
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://flagduel.com:39100");
```

I tried it with apache stopped and port 80 in my server.js and "ws://flagduel.com" in my Frontend file which worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking the Firewall on the vps providers site?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the port 39100 you are trying to use is not open on your machine in contrast to port 80.

I assume that your server is running Ubuntu. If this is the case, try to run the following command to see if the port is open:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

If you don't see port 39100 in the list of open ports similar to port 80, you need to open the port using the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 39100/tcp
```

Once executed, verify that the port is now open using the previous command.
Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but this doesnt seem to be the problem.  the port 39100/tcp is allow in from anywhere and the port 39100/tcp (v6)  is also allow in from anywhere

Comment: @Rayfl, have you tried to use another port with a smaller value, 8090, for example? While there is no apparent reason why 39100 shouldn't work in your scenario, I tend to use ports with smaller numbers. Is any specific reason for you to use 39100? Additionally, what kind of error do you see when trying to connect with a client?

Comment: i tried using the port 8080 and it doesnt work. In the ubuntu console I dont get any errror message, I only get a error message on my Frontend, the "chrome console" shows "WebSocket connection to 'ws://flagduel.com:39100/' failed: " or when i try with the server listening to port 8080 and changing the Frontend i get "WebSocket connection to 'ws://flagduel.com:8080/' failed:"